# CDC Error - NULL Source Schema and Source Table - Error msg on both enable and disable table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, change-data-capture

Today I re-enabled CDC on the primary node of an availability group.  When the jobs were created the cleanup job failed with the following error:

> Could not delete change table entries made obsolete by a change in one or more low water marks for capture instances of database DB1. The failure occurred when executing the command 'delete top( @p1 )  from [cdc].[dbo_Table1_CT] where __$start_lsn < @p2 '. The error returned was 208: 'Invalid object name 'cdc.dbo_Table1_CT'.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 22852).

Using `sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture` I can see for the invalid object name that there is an entry for the `capture_instance`, but the `source_schema` and `source_table` are NULL.  Both enabled and disabling the table fails with the following errors:

> Disable:
>
> Change data capture instance 'dbo_Table1' has not been enabled for the source table 'dbo.Table1'.

> Enable:
>
> Could not create a capture instance because the capture instance name 'dbo_Table1' already exists in the current database.

I'm at a loss on how to get this either removed from CDC or updated so the NULLs don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CDC table has been orphaned.

You can try connecting using the [DAC connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver16) and dropping that table.

Easiest is to connect using `sqlcmd`

```
sqlcmd.exe -A -D YourDb
```

Then just drop the history table

```
DROP TABLE [cdc].[dbo_Table1_CT];
GO
```

You may also want to drop the functions if they exist

```
DROP FUNCTION cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Table1_CT;
GO
DROP FUNCTION cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Table1_CT;
GO
```